# How to use custom font files which are added in document directory in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

i have tried to add custom fonts in application at run time.
so i have added those .ttf files into the document directory.
Now i want to access those files with font name in my application.
so please Suggest how to add custom fonts in Application at run time.

Thanks.

Comment: Check below link for adding custom font https://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: He wants to use a font "at run time". None of the above links are about that.

Comment: HI Friend Thanks , my requirement is this 
i have added some fonts in plist file , those are working fine but now some font links are coming in api , so those font files i have save in document directory. so i want how to save those files in plist with existing font files and how to get font names from those files.

Comment: how to use @font-face in ios application with webview

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. You need to have the font on compile time. Added in the resource and also it needs to be mentioned in info.plist.

Please see the below link from apple on how to add custom font in app. There is no way other then this.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app